# flex 4.1 mx:Image: how can i configure a fallback image that will be shown if link is broken

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm using flex 4.1 to write an application and I was wondering how can I configure that whenever I try to load an image and the link is broken it will show a different image that i have embedded into my application.

I'm loading an Image using `mx:Image`.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the brokenImageSkin on the mx:Image to whatever image you'd like. That way your Images will default to the specified image when loading fails.  Here's an example:  http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/02/setting-a-custom-broken-image-skin-for-the-image-control-in-flex/

Comment: I resolved it by setting the brokenImageSkin attribute of the mx:Image to a class that I created with the requested image embeded: [Embed(source='pics/broken_user_image.jpg')] private var brokenImage:Class;

Answer (score 1):

In the HTTP Request you can add a IO Error Event. 
When this event is triggered, you can use the embedded image instead.

Comment: can you please provide a brief example ?

Comment: I don't have code like this on my library. But what you do is:

On creationcomplete of the component/module/application you try to catch the image. You can do this with an URLRequest + Loader. On this request you add a IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR listerner and an Event.COMPLETE listener.

When the error event is triggered, you just make a new instance of Image with as source the embeded image.

When the complete event is triggered, you can just place the loader on the screen.

Sample code at: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Loader.html

Comment: this solution will work but it may be a bit too much work just to resolve broken images issues.